# Removing Responding from memory cache messages form info log level

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server, weboptimizer

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application uses Weboptimizer (https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer) in Debian linux.

In startUp.cs I have:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddWebOptimizer();
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    { 
        ...
        app.UseWebOptimizer();
        ...
    }
```

syslog contains large number of information messages like

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: WebOptimizer.AssetMiddleware[1000]

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]:       Request started for '/css/siteerp.css'
> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: WebOptimizer.AssetBuilder[1001]

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]:       Responding from memory cache for '/css/siteerp.css'

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: WebOptimizer.AssetMiddleware[1000]

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]:       Request started for '/lib/jquery/jquery.js'

> Apr 18 09:12:26 c202-76 kestrel-store[28711]: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: WebOptimizer.AssetBuilder[1001]

How to disable those messages for WebOptimizer only to make log more compact? I havent found any documentation about log config.

Default appsettings.json is used:

```
{

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be logged from the WebOptimizer namespace (I checked the source on github) which should make it easy to filter out using appsettings. Just add a "WebOptimizer" key and set it to only show "Warning" and higher.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "WebOptimizer": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```